# Why C++ allows defining objects under case labels even though those cases don't match the checked value on contrary to if-statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

If I declare/define an object in a `if` single statement then that object is visible only within the `if` statement and it is defined and allocated only if the `if` condition succeeds.

```
if(true)
   int x = 10;
std::cout << x << '\n'; // error: x is not in scope
```

This is really so logical but why this doesn't apply to `case` statement too?

```
char c = 'b';

switch(c){
   case 'a':
       int value; // ok. not-initialized
   break;
   case 'b':
       value = 100; // why still visible and when initialized? (this is an assignment)
       std::cout << value << '\n'; // 100
   break;
}
```

- As you can see `c` has the value `b` so the first case label `case 'a'` is not executed so when `value` is defined as long as an object is defined when control passes through its definition?
- Why `value` is visible under case label `case 'b'` as long as it is defined under a case label that is not executed?
- What is the point in allowing that? (defining objects even the case label under which they are defined doesn't match)?

Comment: See the `case` label as some sort of `goto` into a block of statements. See [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), for an example, how deep the rabbit hole goes.

Answer (score 3):

The block of the `switch` statement starts at opening curly brace and closes at closing one. The `break` instructions do not mark any end of block.

So both cases belongs to the same instruction block and share the same local variables.

To limit the variable visibility to a block you need to add more curly braces:

```
switch(c){
   case 'a':{
       int value; // ok. not-initialized
   }
   break;
   case 'b':{
       value = 100; // You should get an error now
       std::cout << value << '\n'; // 100
   }
   break;
}
```

So the remaining question is why `break` is not an end of block?
I would say that because break may be conditional.

```
switch(c){
   case 'a':
       int value; // ok. not-initialized
       if (condition)
           break;
   case 'b':
       value = 100; // It is normal in this case to be able to refer to previously defined variable 
       std::cout << value << '\n'; // 100
   break;
}
```

Though I don't see a real use case for such code!

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement and an `if` statement are relatively similar on how they are compiled, that is they both translate into a *conditional jump* in assembly. The main difference is that `if` branches are always mutually exclusive - if you enter the `if`, you are never entering the `else` - but `switch` branches are not. So it makes sense for the compiler to behave accordingly.

We usually insert a `break` at the end of each `case` because otherwise the instructions from the following `case`s would be executed too. For example:

```
int x = 1;
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "x was 1";
        // No break!
    case 2:
        std::cout << "... But was it also 2?" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Spookily outputs:

> x was 1... But was it also 2?

Basically `switch` is a jump instruction, `case` specifies where to land but says **nothing** about jumping out again. That job is done by `break`.

Using the dreaded `goto` statements and labels, a very similar code would be this:

```
int x = 1;
if (x == 1)
    goto x_was_1;
else if (x == 2)
    goto x_was_2;
else
    goto out;
x_was_1:
std::cout << "x was 1";
x_was_2:
std::cout << "... But was it also 2?" << std::endl;
goto out;
out:
// Rest of the code...
```

Which outputs the same thing. You can also see how adding a `break` is equivalent to adding `goto out` in this case.

In conclusion, the content of a `switch` statement is a single code block and all the variables declared inside it are visible throughout *because* you may traverse the whole block. Just like you expect variables to be seen below a `break` in a `while` loop, you can expect them to be visible in this case too. Though I believe using this is extremely bad practice, very unreadable and likely useless.